# Set property after command

Tags: wpf, silverlight, telerik, rad-controls

I have a `StatusBar` below the screen in SL4 (using PRISM), just a very simple `Telerik` `RadDockPanel`.

I also have a menu (Telerik `RibbonView` with `RadRibbonGroup` and `RadRibbonToggleButton`). When the toggle button is pressed, I want to set the text to 'ON' and 'OFF', and I want to hide the status bar, but... only in XAML (not using code behind).

I believe this is a common SL/WPF coding practice... but how ?

Answer (score 0):

Have to use [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx) (check example bellow on page by link that I provided) and [ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.objectanimationusingkeyframes.aspx) to change properties that aren't animated (Text, Visibility so on).

Check good [example in other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942548/setting-a-property-with-an-eventtrigger) on so.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `DataTrigger` in your window like this -

```
<StatusBar.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyRadRibbonToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}"
                Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</StatusBar.Style>
```

In case you can't use `ElementName` binding then you can use a property in your ViewModel(corresponding to `RadRibbonToggleButton` state). Similar `Trigger` can be created for a `TextBlock`/`Label` to show On/Off text.

This is how I implement this kind of functionality in WPF/MVVM applications;

You may have to apply some hack to make this work with telerik controls.