# DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Please help on this issue and I'm not sure how to handle this.

I've combox box and datagrid. When ever I've selected combox value datagrid should be loaded with new data and that works perfectly. But I've DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate with checkbox when I checked all the column with checkbox is also checked and also worked with unchecked as well. Both are fine.

Now my issue is when i selected combobox, datagrid --> headertemplate checkbox should be unchecked. IS there any event I can fire for this? My code below.

Combox is outside the datagrid.

```
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Name="checkadded" Margin="6,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Name="ChkAllAdd" IsChecked="False" Width="50" Loaded="chkallLoaded" Checked="ChkAll_Checked"  Unchecked="ChkAll_Unchecked"  IsThreeState="False" Padding="4,3,4,3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                    </DataGrid.Columns>                        

                    <DataGrid.Resources>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#686868"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="Bold" />
                        </Style>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#93A8A9"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>

                    </DataGrid.Resources>

                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a ControlTemplate for Content Control and place your DataGrid and ComboBox Xaml in that. Now you can create an EventTrigger for Combobox and there you can set the CheckedBox Checked using element name in binding. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942548/setting-a-property-with-an-eventtrigger) can be helpfull.

Comment: I've done with different way but anyhow thanks for your reply

Comment: i am interested to see your solution. you can give that as answer and alsi accept it

Comment: I've removed the header template since it was taking too much to handle so I've created two buttons with select all and un select all...these two clicks will loop the data grid and select and unselect the check boxes.