# How to display a pop-up?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I created a pop-up and want to show it when a button has been clicked. But it doesn't work because it waits for finishing button's duty.

I don't want to use "timer, thread and background worker" because I already can do it with that. I am looking for an another solution…

Here is my code:

```
void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingOpen();

    if (cmbvideoserver.Text == "Youtube")
        SearchInYoutube();
    else if (cmbvideoserver.Text == "Vimeo")
        SearchInVimeo();

    LoadingClose();
}

public void LoadingOpen()
{
    myPopup.IsOpen = true;
    Common.Popup = true;
    window.Opacity = 0.3;
}

public void LoadingClose()
{
    myPopup.IsOpen = false;
    Common.Popup = false;
    window.Opacity = 1;
}
```

and the XAML:

```
<Window Name="window" x:Class="youtube.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="window_Loaded">
  <Canvas Name="main">
    <Popup Name="myPopup" IsOpen="False" PopupAnimation="Slide"
           Margin="100,10,20,0"  Placement="Center" >  
      <Label Content="Loading..."></Label>
    </Popup>
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

How can I show popup on my main window ? (without any thread,timer and background controls/classes)

Comment: Set PlacementTarget property of popup.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, I think that is not necessary because the its already in main and also I setted Placement property in xaml and already pop-up appears (but not at true time)

Comment: check that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361209/how-to-open-a-wpf-popup-when-another-control-is-clicked-using-xaml-markup-only

Answer (score 0):

You can show Windows as dialogs by useing the [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

Comment: but mypopup hasnt any kind of show methods.. ? and i think that if it even exists , the result will not be changed..

Comment: Harun Abi - Did you mean that your Window doesnt have any ShowDialog() method???? Well, ideally speaking, it should have.