# WPF Popup IsOpen issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

Using a concept found [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8946055/24399). **Note that the `ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible` is bound to `Popup.IsOpen`, with `StaysOpen="False"`.** This should mean that touching anywhere *outside* the `Popup` would cause it to close. However...

Touching/Clicking on an `ListBoxItem` in the `ItemsControl` won't close the `Popup`, as is intended. Touching anywhere else within the `Popup` *does* close it. That doesn't seem to add up, according to how this is set up.

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True">
    <Border Name="Root">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_Toggle"
                  ClickMode="Release"
                  IsHitTestVisible="{Binding ElementName=PART_Popup,
                                             Path=IsOpen,
                                             Mode=OneWay,
                                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverter}}"/>
    </Border>
    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
           IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PART_Toggle,
                            Path=IsChecked}"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_Toggle}"
           StaysOpen="False">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Grid>
                <!-- Anything here (outside of the Item) -->
                <ItemsControl>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <!-- Anything in this item template works. The popup does not close -->
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**Edit:  Solved**

Turns out this was happening because it was inside a custom control which was derived from `ListBox`. It didn't seem relevant at the time I made this question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was happening because it was inside a custom control which was derived from ListBox. It didn't seem relevant at the time I made this question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case the problem is either the position or size of the popup. When trying your code it did work, however I had to set `Placement="Center"` on the Popup and set the size of the grid inside the popup.

Without the former, the popup was not placed inside the while without the latter the popup's size was just that of its content (meaning there was no outside to click).

Try first setting the Popup's background to Red or something to see if the popup is actually positioned and sized correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, it was not the right one, you couldn't possible have helped unfortunately. After a couple hours of debugging, it turned out to be that it was because it was within a custom control's `DataTemplate`. This control was derived from `ListBox` and was causing the strange behavior. I modified it and it works as expected.